# HttpClient.PostAsync slow first time

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

after some benchmarks I realized that every time I started my app the first request would take much more time then the next ones. 500ms for the first one and 120ms for the next ones one average.

I have cookies set in the HttpClient and also UseProxy set to false. The HttpClient is also initialized and a make a dummy request but not await it to try to overcome this issue.

Anyone with some new ideias? I'm building a UWP app.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for this.  The app pool is warming up, routes are being built, DI containers may be registering object graphs, caching is occurring, execution plans are being generated and cached, etc etc etc.  This is simply par for the course and to be expected.

Comment: JIT overhead, DNS lookup... these could easily account for the missing 380ms.

Comment: @David, this should be the answer.

Comment: @Shadetheartist fair enough :).  Added.

Comment: When you do a ping what is the TTL?  The ttl indicates the number of hops for the connection.  The routing could be setup to use DNS or just the IP and masks of the interface(s).  There is also a delay of the timer tick service in routing the data from the application to the ethernet interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons for this. The app pool is warming up, routes are being built, DI containers may be registering object graphs, caching is occurring, execution plans are being generated and cached, etc etc etc. This is simply par for the course and to be expected.

As mentioned in the comments by spender, there are also other concerns such as JIT overhead and DNS lookups.

You should always assume application warmup time will be required.  It is considered best practice to warm up the application on first run to ensure quick responses for consumers of your application.  You can't avoid this warmup cost, nor should you try to do so.  Rather, structure your deployments so that you are able to warm up the application before users hit it, such as proper load balancing and server rotation.

Comment: Marked as answered. Thanks for the comments.